# Number of lower arc segments in intersecting circles

Tags: circles

Let N circles intersect each other as many times as possible (no circles passing through the same point). How many lower spring segments (not overlapping) are formed?

I got this far with the question: Since two circles will intersect at most two points, the number of intersection points that a circle will make with the previous n-1 circle must be 2(n-1).
For example, the 2nd circle cuts the other at 2 points (there are  4 sub circle segment), while the 3rd circle cuts the other two at 4 points(there are  12 sub circle segment).
How can we generalize this? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any comment?